# How does use VB to delete Application Event

Tags: vb.net

now i know how do use VB to view Application Event, but i dont know how do use VB to delele Application Event, someone in here, can help me.

my code to show Application Event

```vb
dim WMI_function = "Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile='Application'"       
dim Fields_to_load = "Logfile,Message,type"
dim fail_description = " Access to " + WMI_function + " is protected"
Try
    output_wmi_function_data_instances(WMI_function,Fields_to_load,2000)
Catch
    rw(fail_description)
End Try
```

PS/ please help me, and only use VB thanks you very much.

Comment: This question is tagged in *4* different languages. Can you please tell us which one you need help with?

Comment: He only use VB thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea which language to provide you with so ill go with the first, VB.NET.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Delete("MyCustomLog")
```

Hope this helps..